# Trying to return a class type giving error

Tags: swift

I am trying to return a class type in my swift code, but no matter what code I try I keep getting endless error for optional, below is my code that checks if an id is inside a class and matched with id in another class I should return that user... below is my code and CoreData relationship....

I keep getting error - in Friends section

```
Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
```

How can I return the user that matches the friend in list ? please guide , thanks

//-----Code

```
import SwiftUI

struct DetailView: View {
   
    let user: CachedUser
    @State private var users = [CachedUser]()
    @State private var friends = [CachedFriend]()
    var body: some View {
        Form {
            List {
                Section("Name") {
                    Text(user.wrappedName)
                        .font(.body)
                }
                Section("email") {
                    Text(user.wrappedEmail)
                }
                Section("Registration Date") {
                    Text(user.wrappedEmail)
                }
                Section("Company") {
                    Text(user.wrappedCompany)
                }
                Section("Is Active") {
                    Image(systemName: user.isActive  ? "checkmark.circle.fill" : "xmark.octagon.fill")
                        .foregroundColor(user.isActive  ? Color.green : Color.red)
                }
                Section("Friends") {
                    ForEach(user.cachedFriend) {item in
                        NavigationLink {
                            DetailView(user: users.first(where: { itemFriend in
                                itemFriend.id == item.id
                            })! ) // <-------ERROR
                        } label: {
                            Text(item.wrappedName)
                        }
                    }
                }
 
            }
    
        }

    }
 
}
```

//-----

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure exactly what you are trying to do but why not have an `if` condition around the NavigationLink

```
if let friend = users.first(where: { itemFriend 
    itemFriend.id == item.id
}) {
    NavigationLink { …
    //pass friend to your view instead
}
```

Comment: thanks, I am trying to click on any of the  the friends  of the user in list and then show the same view that showed the current user but now with data of friend fetched from CachedUser, I tried as you had suggest, but now I cannot seem to see any friends in the user , please suggest, I have updated code in question at very top as per your suggestions

Comment: That sounds like a different problem to me and I don't see the point of adding my code to your question. Given this and your previous question is it very hard to understand how your relationships and computed properties works and what they should contain.

Comment: in CoreData due to fact that everything is treated as optional my logic that I used in Struct is not working in Struct it was like this ----


    func findFriend(id: String) -> User {
        guard let user = results.first(where: { user in
            user.id == id
        })
        else {
            return results.first!
        }
        
        return user
    }
    , I passed it to the Navigationlink argument, but here when I am using CoreDataProperties , its always giving some error , thanks

Comment: `else { return results.first! }` so if you can't find a matching user you just return any random user? Is a friend always a user, that is does every CachedFriend also exist in CachedUser?

Comment: yes ,it does, it is in the user list, each friend is also a user .....

Comment: Then you should not have a specific entity for friends, just one for users with a relationship pointing back to user for friends

Comment: thanks a lot , its some one else logic , so I get stuck on some really minor points